# redirect output of python script to file

Tags: shell, io-redirection

How do I get the output of this python script to append to a log file

`sudo inotifywait -mr --format '%e%w%f' --event move $srdir | python3 /usr/bin/m-sync.py $bkdir $srdir >> /mnt/msync.py.log2` doesn't work. No error message, just an empty un-modified log file.

If I do just `sudo inotifywait -mr --format '%e%w%f' --event move $srdir | python3 /usr/bin/m-sync.py $bkdir $srdir` the output spits out to the console as expected.

Ultimately  `sudo inotifywait -mr --format '%e%w%f' --event move $srdir | python3 /usr/bin/m-sync.py $bkdir $srdir >> /mnt/msync.py.log2` is runs from a script as a service by systemd, but I don't think that's relevant since when I run it from the command line manually it still doesn't log.

In all cases the script actually does it's job correctly, I just can't get it's output into a log.

The python script just incase it matters:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import sys
import time
from subprocess import call
src = ""
bkdir = sys.argv[1]
srdir = sys.argv[2]
while True:
        line = sys.stdin.readline()
        event, path = line.split("/",1)
        path="/"+path.rstrip();
        if event in  ["MOVED_FROM","MOVED_FROM,ISDIR"]:
                src = path.replace(srdir, bkdir, 1)
        if event in ["MOVED_TO","MOVED_TO,ISDIR"]:
                dst  =  path.replace(srdir, bkdir, 1)                    
                sys.stdout.write(time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") + " mv " + src + " " + dst )
                call(["mv", src, dst])
```

Edit: Apparently `sudo inotifywait -mr --format '%e%w%f' --event move $srdir | sudo python3 /usr/bin/m-sync.py $bkdir $srdir >> /mnt/msync.py.log2` run from  the command line does work. Notice the second sudo before invoking python. However when run by systemd everything is root by default and still doesn't output to the log.

Comment: It is always advantageous to fill in as many details as possible, instead of just saying "it doesn't work". If you don't get any error message, mention that too. In this case I suspect the fault lies in that only the first part of the pipeline is run as root, i.e. the sudo only applies to the inotifywait command, not to what's after the pipe symbol.

Comment: Do you not get output in the log while the script is running, or even after the script finishes do you still have only an empty file?

Comment: @Johan Myréen Ah! You are right in the case of me running the it from the command line. `sudo inotifywait -mr --format '%e%w%f' --event move $srdir | sudo python3 /usr/bin/m-sync.py $bkdir $srdir >> /mnt/msync.py.log2` does update the log. However when run by systemd everything already was running as root and still didn't update it.

Answer (score 2):

From https://stackoverflow.com/a/3167526/7192818

> I don't know if this applies to python as well, but I think it depends
>   on the operating system that you are running.
>
> On Linux for example, output to terminal flushes the buffer on a
>   newline, whereas for output to files it only flushes when the buffer
>   is full (by default). This is because it is more efficient to flush
>   the buffer fewer times, and the user is less likely to notice if the
>   output is not flushed on a newline in a file.
>
> You might be able to auto-flush the output if that is what you need.

So in the python script adding `sys.stdout.flush()` after the write makes it behave as expected.

Meh.