# How to capture the output of a Python program running in a subshell?

Tags: bash, python, subshell

I'm trying to run a python program at startup by putting the following lines into `etc/rc.local`:

```
(cd /home/pi/CODE/weather-project/weather-station &&
python main.py) &>> log.txt &
```

The program runs fine, but log.txt is empty, my print statements are not logged into log.txt, except when I kill the Python process it'll contain `Terminated`. It also works fine when I remove the `&` sign from the end (but this is something I do not want).

How do I get bash to write the output of a Python program into a file if this program runs in a subshell. I'm using Bash 5.

This is the contents of my `log.txt` when running the script from the terminal for a few seconds without the `&` character at the end of the command:

```
Initializing EPD...
VCOM set to -2.06
current time is: 2021-01-02 19:32:48.198797
refresh weather
heat data is not stable (yet?)
```

Comment: It is likely a buffering issue. The Python code is not producing enough output to warrant flushing the output buffer, and it never flushes it explicitly.  See either https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/324824/redirect-output-of-python-script-to-file/325072#325072 or https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/182537/write-python-stdout-to-file-immediately/182541#182541

Comment: Actually it was 2 issues. First the one you mentioned, second for some reason it did not output anything when it was ran from `rc.local`. The solution was to invoke it this way: `cd /home/pi/CODE/weather-project/weather-station &&
sudo bash -c 'python -u main.py &>> /home/pi/CODE/weather-project/weather-station/log.txt' &`

Comment: That could be because `rc.local` wasn't running with `bash` but with `/bin/sh`? In any case, it should be running as root, so you should not need `sudo` in there.